# Linking bash scripts into one script file

Tags: bash

I searched all over the internet and did not find anything simple.

I have a bash script split into multiple files. The main file uses `source` command to require another and so on. I am not an expert, but to install my script I have to move one file in a `$PATH` directory. I know there is hsc to compile scripts but it's needless.

I just need to create a script that replaces every `source "file"` with the file itself. Not that hard, but why did I not find anything online and no one seems to do so?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually install your script with minor to no changes to your script.

Imagine your scripts are all located in `/path/to/scripts/`:

```
$ ls /path/to/scripts
main source1 source2 source3 ...
```

And it runs perfectly from this directory. Then you have two options to install it with minimal intervention.

**Install a wrapper script:**

Instead of making a copy in the `/path/to/PATHDIR`, you install a wrapper script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd /path/to/scripts
./main "$@"
```

**Install a softlink and update `main`:**

```
$ cd /path/to/PATHDIR
$ ln /path/to/scripts/main .
```

Update main that it always changes the working directory first.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd /path/to/scripts
....
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
cd $(dirname $(readlink -f "$0"))
```

Comment: Ok, but where should the source folder be moved to? If someone downloads my git repo and installs he will probably remove the folder right away. Thanks!

Comment: You can move the entire source folder under `path/to/pathdir/sourcefolder` if you want.

Comment: @RandomDev You can move the entire source folder under `/path/to/pathdir/sourcefolder` if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `source $0` with reasonable reliability - caveats when $0 is not a full path and your script changes directory or changes $path. However, I guess you might also want to structure the subroutines.

Back in the old days of DOS, I had a convention that if the $1 was `--call` then $2 was the label to goto and shift 2, though you had to capture $0 before shifting, etcetera.

However bash supports functions, so you shouldn't need to use `source $0`
http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-8.html
Just put the body of the child script inside a function and call it within the script.

Of course, you might still want the --call command-line feature so you can access the functionality directly, oh and to unit test it.